# ls -lth | awk '{printf.... to get list of files and add a header

Tags: linux, shell, awk, printf, ls

I need a command that lists the contents in a specific directory. I need the filename, date created and size of the file. This is what I have.

```
ls -lth | awk '{printf "%s   %s-%s %s   %s\n",$9,$6,$7,$8,$5}' >> list.txt
```

And I'm getting something like this:

```
   -    
meb.20140112-030003.img   Jan-12 13:49   755G
meb.20140105-030003.img   Jan-5 13:55   769G
meb.20140108-030003.img   Jan-7 10:55   739G
```

Which is fine. But I need to delete the first line "-" and instead add a header to the file. I'm looking for something like this:

```
FILE_NAME                 DATE          SIZE
meb.20140112-030003.img   Jan-12 13:49   755G
meb.20140105-030003.img   Jan-5 13:55   769G
meb.20140108-030003.img   Jan-7 10:55   739G
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

> I need the filename, date created and size of the file.

You should not parse `ls` command's output and instead use `stat` command like this:

```
stat -c '%n %y %s' *
```

Comment: It is usually unsafe because of potential presence of space/newline in file names. See this article for more details: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 1):

Some like this?

```
ls -lth | awk 'BEGIN {print "FILE_NAME                 DATE          SIZE"} NR>1 {printf "%s   %s-%s %s   %s\n",$9,$6,$7,$8,$5}'
```

Comment: If the filenames don't have spaces, it might look nicer if it was filtered through `column -t`.

Comment: What does the NR>1 do? I know NR will give you the number of lines but NR>1?

Comment: @andresg3, `NR` is the current record number, not the number of lines. `NR==1` means awk is processing record number 1. Usually, a record == a line, unless you redefine `RS`